# Cannot change field value

Tags: c#, xna, field

EDIT: Found it. There was an error in player constructor. I changed my game system, so it uses IDs for entites and tiles. Before that i had to do new instances of everything. I forgot to put inventory initialization from constructor to PostInitialize() so it used the null world of non existing entity. Thank you all.

---

i have a problem. I am doing an XNA game and i need to change entity's map so it can do it's stuff but I've ran into a problem. Method receives argument map that is not null, i set entity.currentMap to the argument but currentMap is still null.

```
public Entity getCopy(Vector2 po, Map.Map map)
    {
        Entity t = (Entity)this.MemberwiseClone();
        t.currentMap = map;
        t.Position = po;
        t.LoadTextures();
        t.PostInitialize();
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about t.currentMap or entity.currentMap in some calling function? If you set a breakpoint on this method, are you saying 'map' is not null and t.currentMap is still null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you say that `map` is *definitely* not null when being passed in.  Thus, there are two possibilities.

**One:** The setter for `currentMap` is not working.  Either post the code associated with the setter or make sure it's actually storing the value properly by stepping into it.  Make sure on the very next line, the value is still there.

**Two:** The value is getting lost elsewhere in the method. Are you sure `LoadTextures` and/or `PostInitialize` are not clearing the `currentMap` variable?

Comment: currentMap is field, not a property. Maybe there is a PostInitialize error, that would solve the mistery why bullet bugs so much.

Comment: The debugger is your friend..